# Points $\sqrt2$ units apart in a $4\times4$ square

Tags: geometry

> What is the minimum number of points randomly chosen in a $4\times4$ square (each point can be at the square's boundary) so that there is always a pair of $2$ points not more than $\sqrt2$ units apart?

Let the number of points be $n$. We can divide the square into $16$ unit squares. If $n\ge17$, by the pigeonhole principle, then at least one unit square has multiple points, and the distance of those points is not more than $\sqrt2$. If $n=16$, it can happen that no unit square has multiple points. But, I have not been able to construct an example where every $2$ points are more than $\sqrt2$ units apart.

How to construct an example of the distribution of $16$ points in the large square such that every $2$ points are more than $\sqrt2$ units apart? If such an example cannot be constructed, why, and what is the maximum number of points such that it is possible that every $2$ points are more than $\sqrt2$ units apart?

---

My attempt:

Put $4$ points near the bottom, horizontally $1\frac13$ units apart, as in this picture:[image: ![the image]

But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: You need examples of points *more than* $\sqrt 2$ units apart.  The answer is "one more than the maximum number of points so that no two are within $\sqrt 2$ units of one another."  It doesn't sound like a pigeonhole problem to me.

Comment: Hmm... this seems to become the [circle packing problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirclePacking.html) of trying to pack circles of radius $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ into a square of side length $4+\sqrt{2}$ (*extend the margins of the square by $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ in each direction since the points in our original problem correspond to centers of circles and the points could have been on the outer edge of the original grid*)

Comment: The ratio of the radius of the circles to the side-length of the square in this case would be $\frac{\sqrt{2}/2}{4+\sqrt{2}}\approx 0.1306\dots$. According to [this page](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/csq.html), this would seem to imply the true maximum number of points that can fit in the square without two being within range of one another would be $13$ and fitting $15$ would be impossible. (*or I could be reading it incorrectly and its actually $12$*)...

Comment: [This page](https://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/cirinsqu/) provides similar information as well as nice visuals, except being phrased in terms of a unit square like the earlier link, it is phrased in terms of unit circles.

Comment: That solved the problem.